# Почему интерфейсы репозиториев декларируются в доменной модели?

Tags: ddd

Если доменный слой не управляет сохранением и извлечением агрегатов из хранилища, то зачем объявлять интерфейсы репозиториев в доменной модели? Почему это не делать в инфраструктурном слое?

Answer (score 0):

Наличие репозитория не означает, что у вас будет что-то персиститься. Вы, например, можете запустить свой скрипт как демон и все держать в оперативной памяти. Но при этом вам все равно нужно будет добавлять и, главное, искать агрегаты. Также у вас может быть доменное ограничение на уникальность элемента по каком-то признаку, вот здесь без репозитория уже не обойтись. 
Да, при таком сохранение данных все данные будут потеряны при перезагрузки демона, но возможно именно такое поведение и надобно.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что, у вас могут быть доменные сущности, которым тоже требуется доступ к доменным объектам. Например доменные сервисы. Если таких нет, то этого можно не делать.